# Sharepoint Controls and CssClass

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, page-layout

Im building some page layouts in SharePoint Designer 2010. If i do this:

```
<PublishingWebCOntrols:RichImageField 
 FieldName="Image Caption" 
 runat="server" 
 CssClass="imageCaption" />
```

The CSS class is not added when the page is rendered. I see the same when I use SharePointWebControls:FieldValue as well, but that is a little more expected as it render the value without tags. Any help?

Comment: Hmm... It's certainly a valid property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.richimagefield_members.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`PublishingWebControls` is misspelled.  Is that a direct copy and paste from your page, or a misspelling on here?  It should be:

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichImageField 
 FieldName="Image Caption" 
 runat="server" 
 CssClass="imageCaption" />
```